# NOAA API Web Service Chance of Rain Numbers

Tags: weather, forecast, noaa

I’m using [NOAA's API Web Service](https://www.weather.gov/documentation/services-web-api#/default/get_points__point__stations) to download a point forecast. I'm doing this with a python script that uses the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and [noaa_sdk](https://pypi.org/project/noaa-sdk/) libraries. I successfully pulled a json file for a specific location (lat, long) and I get the 7-day forecast. The problem is chance of rain reports are not quantified with numbers but rather say things like “Slight chance of rain” or “mostly cloudy” or "snow likely". Can these types of statements be quantified with a number? Does the word "likely" mean there is a 50% chance or greater? Does "slight chance" mean less than 50%? Is there a better way to get numbers for the chance of rain in a forecast through their API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I found the site I need: [National Digital Forecast Database (NDFD) REST Web Service](https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/rest.php#XML_contents). Next, I found [this library](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr) for making the request for the data. Now, I'm able to get a 7-day forecast with precip and chance of rain numbers.